# Cannot install @material-ui/pickers (ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to install the library @material-ui/pickers by running:

```
npm i @material-ui/pickers
```

But this error shows up:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: five@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/pickers@3.2.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
npm ERR!       @material-ui/pickers@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.4" from @material-ui/pickers@3.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
npm ERR!   @material-ui/pickers@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here are my package.json dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

I thought there was maybe some problems in other parts of my file, so I started a create-react-app from scratch and tried again, but the same error is still occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to check out the new Material UI DatePicker from over [here](https://next.material-ui.com/components/date-picker/). If I understood correctly@material-ui/pickers [isn't used anymore](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/2157).

Answer (score 0):

`@material-ui/pickers` required `react` to be 16.13.1 or higher but not to 17.xx.xx. Right now you are using React version 17.0.1. You can try to downgrade the React to version 16 and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I even had this error and what I did was simply closed my VScode because the project was open in it and again tried to install the package and guess what it works. You can try this solution hopefully it works.